# Download files until it works

Tags: r

I have the following loop function, the website i download data is not so good, sometimes gives error and the loop stop. How to create a function to try download it until it works?

```
for (i in 1:length(urls)) {
  
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
  
  if (file.exists(paste0("Data/", file.name[i],".zip"))) {
    message(paste0(file.name[i], ".zip", '\tFile already exists'), 
            appendLF = TRUE)
  } else {
    download.file(urls[i], 
                  destfile = paste0("Data/", file.name[i],".zip"),
                  mode = "wb")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this function years ago in another post, which I cannot find again. But I am using this bad boy since then.

```
library(futile.logger)
library(utils)

retry <- function(expr, isError=function(x) "try-error" %in% class(x), maxErrors=5, sleep=0) {
  attempts = 0
  retval = try(eval(expr))
  while (isError(retval)) {
    attempts = attempts + 1
    if (attempts >= maxErrors) {
      msg = sprintf("retry: too many retries [[%s]]", capture.output(str(retval)))
      flog.fatal(msg)
      stop(msg)
    } else {
      msg = sprintf("retry: error in attempt %i/%i [[%s]]", attempts,  maxErrors, 
                    capture.output(str(retval)))
      flog.error(msg)
      warning(msg)
     
    }
    if (sleep > 0) Sys.sleep(sleep)
    retval = try(eval(expr))
  }
  return(retval)
}
```

Keep in mind that this is a custom function and therefore has to be loaded in addition to your usual packages.

How to use:

```
retry(any_function(x), maxErrors = 100, sleep = 20)
```

**maxErrors  = number of retrys**

**sleep = time between the trys** (in seconds)

Answer (score 0):

how about a combination of `try` and `repeat`?

```
download_until_success <- function(url, destfile, ..., maxcount = 5) {
  
  count <- 0
  
  repeat{
    
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
    try(download.file(url, destfile, ...))
    
    count <- count + 1
    
    if (file.exists(destfile) || count >= maxcount)
      break
    
  }
  
}
```

for example, if I try it with the non-existent URL `"h"` you see it continues indefinitely:

```
download_until_success(
  "h", # <- doesn't exist but shows how the download will restart again and again
  tempfile()
)

trying URL 'h'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, ...) : cannot open URL 'h'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile, ...) :
  URL 'http://h/': status was 'Couldn't resolve host name'
trying URL 'h'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, ...) : cannot open URL 'h'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile, ...) :
  URL 'http://h/': status was 'Couldn't resolve host name'
trying URL 'h'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, ...) : cannot open URL 'h'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile, ...) :
  URL 'http://h/': status was 'Couldn't resolve host name'
trying URL 'h'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, ...) : cannot open URL 'h'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile, ...) :
  URL 'http://h/': status was 'Couldn't resolve host name'
trying URL 'h'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, ...) : cannot open URL 'h'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile, ...) :
  URL 'http://h/': status was 'Couldn't resolve host name'
```

you can accomplish the same with a `while` loop if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `tryCatch` combined with a maximum number of attempts can solve the problem. Something along the lines of the following:

```
maxtry <- 10

for (i in seq_along(urls)) {

  Sys.sleep(0.5)
  flname <- paste0(file.name[i],".zip")
  filename <- file.path("Data", flname)
  if (file.exists(filename)) {
    message(paste0(flname, '\tFile already exists'),
            appendLF = TRUE)
  } else {
    ntry <- 0L
    repeat{
      fl <- tryCatch(
        download.file(urls[i],
                      destfile = filename,
                      mode = "wb"),
        error = function(e) e
      )
      not.yet <- inherits(fl, "error")
      if(not.yet) Sys.sleep(3) else break
      ntry <- ntry + 1L
      if(ntry > maxtry) {
        msg <- paste0(flname, "\tReached max tries ", ntry)
        message(msg, appendLF = TRUE)
        break
      }
    }
  }
}
```