# R readLines() failure persists: 'Failure when receiving data from the peer'

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the get_ontology() function, which uses readLines().
It seems to fail 75% of the time:

```r
ncit <- get_ontology(file("https://projects.nextwaretech.net/omicon/ncit/ncit.obo"))

Error in readLines(file) : cannot read from connection
In addition: Warning message:
In readLines(file) :
  URL 'https://projects.nextwaretech.net/omicon/ncit/ncit.obo': status was 'Failure when receiving data from the peer'
```

I have no idea why this is happening / how to address this. Any insight would be much appreciated.

```r
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Devuan GNU/Linux 3 (beowulf)

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.3.5.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] httr_1.4.2          tibble_3.1.0        data.table_1.14.0   rentrez_1.2.3       ontologyIndex_2.7   myTAI_0.9.3        
 [7] limma_3.46.0        GEOquery_2.58.0     easyPubMed_2.13     devtools_2.3.2      usethis_2.0.1       ArrayExpress_1.50.0
[13] Biobase_2.50.0      BiocGenerics_0.36.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bitops_1.0-6                matrixStats_0.58.0          fs_1.5.0                    bit64_4.0.5                
 [5] rprojroot_2.0.2             GenomeInfoDb_1.26.4         tools_4.0.4                 utf8_1.2.1                 
 [9] R6_2.5.0                    affyio_1.60.0               DBI_1.1.1                   colorspace_2.0-0           
[13] withr_2.4.1                 tidyselect_1.1.0            prettyunits_1.1.1           processx_3.4.5             
[17] bit_4.0.4                   compiler_4.0.4              preprocessCore_1.52.1       cli_2.3.1                  
[21] xml2_1.3.2                  desc_1.3.0                  DelayedArray_0.16.2         readr_1.4.0                
[25] callr_3.5.1                 XVector_0.30.0              pkgconfig_2.0.3             sessioninfo_1.1.1          
[29] MatrixGenerics_1.2.1        fastmap_1.1.0               rlang_0.4.10                rstudioapi_0.13            
[33] RSQLite_2.2.4               generics_0.1.0              jsonlite_1.7.2              dplyr_1.0.5                
[37] RCurl_1.98-1.3              magrittr_2.0.1              GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.4      Matrix_1.3-2               
[41] oligoClasses_1.52.0         Rcpp_1.0.6                  S4Vectors_0.28.1            fansi_0.4.2                
[45] lifecycle_1.0.0             yaml_2.2.1                  oligo_1.54.1                SummarizedExperiment_1.20.0
[49] zlibbioc_1.36.0             pkgbuild_1.2.0              grid_4.0.4                  affxparser_1.62.0          
[53] blob_1.2.1                  crayon_1.4.1                lattice_0.20-41             Biostrings_2.58.0          
[57] splines_4.0.4               hms_1.0.0                   ps_1.6.0                    pillar_1.5.1               
[61] GenomicRanges_1.42.0        codetools_0.2-18            stats4_4.0.4                pkgload_1.2.0              
[65] XML_3.99-0.6                glue_1.4.2                  remotes_2.2.0               BiocManager_1.30.10        
[69] vctrs_0.3.6                 foreach_1.5.1               testthat_3.0.2              purrr_0.3.4                
[73] tidyr_1.1.3                 assertthat_0.2.1            cachem_1.0.4                xfun_0.22                  
[77] ff_4.0.4                    iterators_1.0.13            tinytex_0.30                memoise_2.0.0              
[81] IRanges_2.24.1              ellipsis_0.3.1
```

Comment: I'm using get_ontology from ontologyIndex currently. The only issue with your second suggestion, which I may try anyways, is that the version of the ontology I'm pulling down will be updated periodically, and I may not know about it. I appreciate the input though.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found the solution: adjust the max timeout (via `options()`) then download the file to temp, load it using `get_ontology()` (ontologyIndex), then delete the temp file, e.g.

```
options(timeout = 5*60)
install.packages("ontologyIndex")
library(ontologyIndex)
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("https://projects.nextwaretech.net/omicon/ncit/ncit.obo", temp)
data <- get_ontology(temp, extract_tags = "minimal")
unlink(temp)
```

You can also retry the download on fail (e.g. [Download files until it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63340463/download-files-until-it-works)) or download the ncit.obo file from a 'more public' url (e.g. http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/ncit.obo)

--

This worked 10 times in a row without issue:

```
#install.packages("ontologyIndex")
for (i in 1:10){
  options(timeout = 5*60)
  library(ontologyIndex)
  temp <- tempfile()
  download.file("http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/ncit.obo", mode = "wget", temp)
  data <- get_ontology(temp)
  unlink(temp)
  rm(data)
  rm(temp)
  Sys.sleep(sample(1:10, 1))
}
```